# DataGridView Value appearing as 1,000 when I would like it to appear as 1000

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `DataGridView` and I am writing integers in to one of the columns, I would like these values not to have a comma in them when the value >= 1000. But at the moment, when i enter a value which is >= 1000 they appear in the form '1,000', the comma could be translated incorrectly in certain areas so I would prefer it to just appear as '1000'. Is there any formatting of the `DataGridViewColumn` that will stop this.

Comment: As per liggett78's answer, there is a good reason that it is being formatted as 1,000 - are you sure you have good reason for changing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the comma could be translated
>   incorrectly in certain areas

If you mean "certain countries/locales" by that then this is incorrect. Your numbers are being formatted according to the rules of the current user's locale, so a comma in one locale would become a dot in other etc. 
Other than that specify "D" or "d" as DataFormatString to format it without any punctuation.

Answer (score 2):

This may help :

```
dataGridView1.Columns["NumericColumn"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "d";
```

[How to: Format Data in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9x2790s.aspx)

[Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)